# Using Conditional Rendering with Visualforce in a PDF

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirment to create a custom document where the font colors change depending on the value of the field. My first thought was Conga but working with the if statement is Word is  a pain. I thought it would be easier to write a visualforce page that renders as a PDF.

Below is the basic code. The color rendering works fine as a web page but as soon as I add renderAs="PDF" I loose the font colors.  Is there a way to make this work?

```
<apex:page id="Region_Health_Check" showHeader="false" standardController="Region__c" docType="html-5.0"
           sideBar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <head>
        <title>Region Health Check Report</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.HealthCheckStyle}"/>
    </head>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="50%" align="left">Email Engagement Score Card</td>
            <td width="50%" align="right">Overall Health Check Score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr width ="100%">
            <td width="50%">
                <span style="font-family: BrownStd; font-size: 24px">
                     <apex:outputText value="{!Region__c.Name}"/>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td  width="50%" align="center">
                <font color="{!if(Region__c.Grade__c='A', 'green', 'blue')}">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!Region__c.Grade__c}" style="font-size: 39px; font-family: BrownStd, SansSerif"/>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Instead of renderAs=pdf" can you try renderAs="advanced_pdf" ? src: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm

Comment: I tried advanced_pdf and the  font colors still did not work..

Comment: @PranayJaiswal i have one question, what if i render the data through the javascript remote method invocation, and then i want print pdf on any event. and how can i get advanced_pdf feature to my org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the color parameter inside the style of the outputText.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Region__c.Grade__c}"
                 style="color:{!if(Region__c.Grade__c='A', 'green', 'blue')}; 
                        font-size: 39px;
                        font-family: BrownStd, SansSerif"
/>
```

I think this should work